# New lines in value attribute - IE11

Tags: html, forms, button, internet-explorer-11

I've got a bit of a strange issue with a very bad website - \n is used to add line breaks in the value attribute of an HTML input.  This is what it looks like when you view the source:

```
<input type="button" name="whatever" value="Poor

Not selected">
```

The value is like that to push the "Not selected" part out of the button so it's not visible (horrible design, I know, not my fault).  It works in all browsers but IE11.  I've tried \r\n, &#10, and adding a break tag (which I knew wouldn't work, but hey).  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Not reproduceable. IE 11 shows “PoorNot selected”, Firefox shows “Poor” and “Not selected” in two lines. If you see something else, your actual code differs from what you have posted here, e.g. some CSS settings shrink the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this input to an actual button tag:

```
<button type="submit" name="whatever" value="Not Selected">Poor</button>
```

That way your value can be different from the "label" on the button and it will still submit the form.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/mm1of4tk/

Comment: Yup that should fix it

Comment: Only problem is that I'm hesitant to change what gets sent to the backend because this codebase is like a long-running game of Jenga lol.  Thanks for the suggestion. I was hoping there was some way to just force IE to recognize \n's. :(

Comment: Think you'll need to go into the server script that handles this form and update it to accept the new value for this input. Its a hacky value anyways, better to fix it now. Post your form-handling script in a new question if you can't figure out what to change.

Comment: This changes the effect (meaning) of the element. The form data sent is different.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Correct. My understanding is that the input value that is passed from IE11 is problematic for the form-handling script though, requiring a change. If I misinterpreted that, OP can simply re-use that value with the \n in it with the button tag, and not suffer the display problem.